# error filepath = folderpath & " *.xlsx"

Tags: vba, filepath

I'm new to VBA.  I found this code on a youtube video to copy data from Multiple Workbooks into Master, which is what I want to do.  However, I get a compile error:  Invalid or unqualified reference when it gets to "*.xlsx"  It does not like the period:  Help gives me this: An identifier beginning with a period is valid only within a With block. This error has the following cause and solution:
The identifier begins with a period. 
Complete the qualification of the identifier or remove the period.
Any suggestions?

```
Sub copyDataFromMultipleWorkbooksIntoMaster()

Dim FolderPath As String, Filepath As String, Filename As String

FolderPath = "G:\control_chart\"

Filepath = FolderPath & “ * .xlsx”

Filename = Dir(Filepath)

Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

Do While Filename <> “”
Workbooks.Open (FolderPath & Filename)
 lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 ActiveWorkbook.Close

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, lastcolumn))
 ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))

Filename = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: remove space before and after `*` so `Filepath = FolderPath & "*.xlsx"`

Comment: Thanks, I did try that but VBA auto corrects and adds the space back in.  How do I make it stay.

Comment: because you are using `“` instead of `"`

Comment: Okay, I typed it in again and it worked!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks cyboashu for point that out.  I will watch carefully in the future.

Comment: use `Option Explicit`, that will notify you before hand for such errors.